# How should I name a header file designed for one structure

Tags: objective-c, c, structure, naming

I have a structure called `NDPlane`, and I want to put it in its own file by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343211/2770572).

To avoid confusion as this just being an Objective-C interface for an `NDPlane` object, how should I name the file? `ndplane.h`, `plane.h`, or `struct_NDPlane.h`, etc...

Comment: I would say `ndplane.h` is a good, intuitive choice.

Comment: Cocoa doesn't typically bother distinguishing between classes and structs in the type name or file name.